# Firebase Messaging token unknown

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I recently changed the Firebase options of my Flutter project. I am using a new Firebase application for my Flutter project with new keys until everything is fine. Where it gets stuck is that I can no longer access the FCM token of my device. I have this exception which throws Error requesting FCM token:

```
[firebase_messaging/unknown] An unknown error has occurred
```

I also share with you the class used.

```
  class FirebaseApi {
  Future<String?> initNotifications() async {
    final _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    late String? deviceToken = '';
    try {
      await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
        alert: true,
        announcement: false,
        badge: true,
        carPlay: false,
        criticalAlert: false,
        provisional: false,
        sound: true,
      );
      final FCMToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
      if (FCMToken != null) {
        deviceToken = FCMToken;
        print('FCM Token: $FCMToken');
      } else {
        final fcmTokenManager = FCMTokenManager();
        var currentToken = await fcmTokenManager.renewToken();
        deviceToken = currentToken;
      }

      initPushNotifications();   
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackground);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error requesting FCM token: $e');
    }
    return deviceToken;
  }

  void handleMessage(RemoteMessage? remoteMessage) {
    print('RemoteMessage : $remoteMessage');
  }

  Future initPushNotifications() async {
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then(handleMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(handleMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(handleMessage);
  }

  Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackground(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  }
}
```